# Technical name (radiometric/photometric/ray-optic) of the physical field that is measured with a camera

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, terminology, camera

A camera (that is FPA and objective) is a device that measures [intensity][1] or radiant intensity vs. two angles (horizontal & vertical). So it generates a representation of the physical quantity

$I(\phi, \theta)$

How is this "field" actually named in physics? I am looking for a radiometric, photometric, ray-optics or similar term.

A few options that come to my mind:

- Intensity field
- Radiant intensity field
- Light field (I think this is something else)

Examples: A voltmeter is a device that measures voltage, a clock is a device that measures time. An impedance analyzer is a device that measures an impedance spectrum (i.e. V/A vs. frequency). But what does a camera measure? (camera including objective, not just the sensor array)

[1]: For simplicity let ignore here color and also non-linear response of typical consumer cameras.

Comment: The field is the electromagnetic field $\mathbf E(\mathbf r, t)$. The intensity is just $|\mathbf E|^2$.

Comment: @JohnRennie I see your point. Perhaps I should have said that I am looking for radiometric, photometric or ray-optics term (which I did not think of when writing the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit that best represents what a camera measures directly is *radiance/luminance*, not radiant/luminous intensity.  I will stick with the photometric versions of these units (luminance, luminous intensity) moving forward.

[Luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance) is defined as "flux per solid angle per projected area".  *Projected* is the key concept here.  (Note that flux per solid angle is also intensity; luminance is therefore intensity per area.)

The projected area concept is what gives the unit its most desired property: its value does not change with distance from the source.  This property allows the unit to represent the human perception of 'brightness': a source seems the same 'brightness' to us whether we are up close to it, or far away.

From wikipedia:
[image: luminance]

The 'S' here is some random surface, but you can imagine a sensor placed there.  A pixel in this sensor (of size dS) represents a projected area from the source.

The 'double solid angle' graphs, where one solid angle is projected from the image back onto the object, is what makes luminance unique.  A camera's pixel doesn't measure intensity directly, because it doesn't know what solid angle its pixel is imaging - you'd have to know the full geometry of the scene to *calculate* intensity.  But that pixel is getting something proportional to luminance, whether it really knows the geometry or not.

A camera's pixel is truly 'projected' onto the original source, via its optics.  I hope the picture helps you visualize this.